# Do methods that return pointers to different objects alloc and init that other object automatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, pointers, memory-management

Let's say I have this code:

```
NSString *inspDate = @"20120515";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *inspectionDate;
inspectionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inspDate];
```

When I check to see that it works (`NSDate` contains the correctly formatted data) it does... but why?

Here I go through the steps:

1. Memory for `NSDateFormatter` is getting allocated and instantiated in the heap. `dateFormatter` is pointing to that location, got it:

   ```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   ```
2. Now `dateFormatter` is being told how to interpret `NSString`'s as a date, ok:

   ```
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
   ```
3. Here's the part I'm hazy on, `inspectionDate` pointer is set to nil. It's not pointing to anything:

   ```
   NSDate *inspectionDate;
   ```
4. How is `dateFormatter` returning a pointer to a `NSDate` when there was no `alloc` or`init` called to `inspectionDate`? Is the implementation of `dateFromString` doing the `alloc` and `init` in its implementation?

   ```
    inspectionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inspDate];
   ```

Helping me visualize this would be a tremendous help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dateFromString` method will instantiate (likely through an alloc/init call at some point, or an `NSDate` convenience method which itself will do the allocation) an `NSDate` object and you assign it to your `inspectionDate` variable. As with any "convenience" method that does not start with `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`, there is no transfer of object ownership, i.e. the instance returned is autoreleased.

Comment: ... and autorelease the returned date.

Comment: The `dateFromString` takes care of allocating and initializing the `NSDate` object for me, I'm just pointing to its creation living in the heap using my `inspectionDate` pointer. Thank you sir!